# ag-grid updateRows with multiple column changes

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to update the records in ag-grid when a transaction happens on certain records. when this transaction is complete, I go back to the database for those specific records and fetch the data, where values from one field are moved to another. Now I am trying to use the updateRows() method to update the rows, which is failing with error `ag-Grid: could not find data item as object was not found`

I could not find anything about the multiple fields in the documentation

```
self.agGridOptions.api.updateRowData({
                        update: result
                    });
```

Is there a property or function that will accept the fields that should be compared when assigning the data?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are calling the correct api.
I believe that the problem is that the grid cannot identify the row that you want to update.

You need to provide a unique identifier for each row in the grid.
Then, the row that you provide in the 'update' parameter in your updateRowData api call must have the same unique identifier.

You can tell the grid which field is the rowId in your data by binding a callback function in the GridOptions, e.g. in the HTML:

```
[getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeIdFromRowData"
```

The obvious way to do this is to use the database primary key for the grid row's unique id.